# Draw a simple box around a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm trying to learn python, and one of the "tasks" asks me to draw a box around a string. For some reason, I can't come to a solution. This is supposed to be super basic so we can't use functions and loops etc.

Here's the task: (I'm stuck on question 2)

1. Load a string via the input () function, and stores the result in a variable.
2. Draw a box around the string. There should be one space before and after the string, and one "=" on each side. Fill in above and below accordingly.

Here's what it's supposed to look like:

```
text: hello

=========
= Hello =
=========
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
string = 'Hello'
box_char = '='
print(box_char*(len(string)+4))
print(box_char,string,box_char)
print(box_char*(len(string)+4))
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Print equals signs as many times as the length of the string + 4
2. Print an equal sign and space, print your string, then another space and equal sign
3. Repeat step one for the bottom.

The len(string) method takes the string and returns length.

Comment: Thank you for the help!